How do I use SF Mono in Chrome?
The SF Mono font is present on modern Macs, but I can't seem to target it in my CSS font stack for Chrome? It works just fine on Safari, but not in Chrome. I know ui-monospace doesn't work (yet) in Chrome, but neither do all these variations:
font-family: 'SF mono', SFMono-Regular, ui-monospace, monospace;

I even tried this to no avail:
@font-face {
    font-family: SFMono-Regular;
    src: local("SFMono-Regular");
}


Your questions is a bit confusing to answer. Elaborate more on your question so that we can have a better idea about the problem.

Not sure what more I can say? It's a very straightforward question, no?

Afaik: SF Mono is not available as a regular/global system font but only in some apps like the console. This post may help https://medium.com/@shashikant.jagtap/getting-apples-sf-mono-font-in-macos-1de5183add84

Didn't find a solution so I ended up embedding the font with @font-face…
